# Definition of differential input resistance

Tags: amplifier, differential, input-impedance

What is a differential input resistance (\$R_{\text{id}}\$) in a differential amplifier? Could you show me the expression for this quantity?

I think it is:

$$R_{id}=\frac{v_{id}}{i_{id}}=\frac{v_{i2}-v_{i1}}{i_{i2}-i_{i1}}$$

I didn't find this expression anywhere, so I need to be sure.

There's an image of a basic differential amplifier:

[image]

Comment: What is an "AMPOP"?

Comment: Can't I use latex in this site to write "$R_{id}$"?

Comment: Texas Instruments defines it as "The small-signal resistance between two ungrounded input terminals." http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sloa083/sloa083.pdf

Comment: write it like this put a backslash before each $ i.e. \$R_{ID}\$

Comment: @ÉlioPereira You have to escape the dollars \\$

Comment: Isn't \$R_{id}\$ something like: \$R_{id}=\frac{v_{id}}{i_{id}}\$, where \$v_{id}=v^+-v^-\$ and analog to \$i_{id}\$?

Comment: Why isn't it that exactly ? Why should it be ? Of course it is !

Comment: I didn't find the expression for this quantity, so I needed to post this question to make sure...

Comment: By the way, @FakeMoustache you can post the answer if it is right

Comment: Sorry, too lazy ;-)

Comment: Too lazy to answer but not too lazy to comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on Sedra's book that \$R_{id}\$ could be determinated by the following way:

1) Plug in a voltage source \$v_{id}\$ on the initial terminals;

2) Link the two input terminals of the differential amplifier.

As this image demonstrates:

[image]

And then just calculate \$R_{id}=\frac{v_{id}}{{i_I}}\$